# XNA Sprite collision class partly not working

Tags: xna-4.0, collision, sprite

EDIT: sprite was derping. Now it just has some problems with continual colliding.

So I have a pixel by pixel sprite collision class that works partly, but only to the right. Trying to go to the left results in there always being a collision.  This is the class itself.

```
  public Boolean collision(Texture2D first, Vector2 position1, Texture2D second, Vector2 position2)
    {

        //gets the bounds of the two sprites
        FirstBounds = new Rectangle((int)(position1.X),
        (int)(position1.Y), first.Width, first.Height);

        SecondBounds = new Rectangle((int)(position2.X),
        (int)(position2.Y), second.Width, second.Height);

        //if they intersect.
            if (FirstBounds.Intersects(SecondBounds))
            {

            Color[] DataA = new Color[first.Width * first.Height];
            first.GetData(DataA);

            Color[] DataB = new Color[second.Width * second.Height];
            second.GetData(DataB);

            int Top = System.Math.Max(FirstBounds.Top, SecondBounds.Top);
            int Bottom = System.Math.Min(FirstBounds.Bottom, SecondBounds.Bottom);
            int Left = System.Math.Max(FirstBounds.Left, SecondBounds.Left);
            int Right = System.Math.Min(FirstBounds.Right, SecondBounds.Right);

            for (int y = Top; y < Bottom; y++)
            {
                for (int x = Left; x < Right; x++)
                {
                    Color ColorA = DataA[(x - FirstBounds.Left) + (y - FirstBounds.Top) * FirstBounds.Width];
                    Color ColorB = DataB[(x - SecondBounds.Left) + (y - SecondBounds.Top) * SecondBounds.Width];

                    if (ColorA.A > 0 && ColorB.A > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                }



            }

            return false;
            }








        return false;

    }
```

Here's the code for the entire class that I am using, yes it is the main class.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{

    // all graphics classes.
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private AnimatedSprite animatedSprite;
    private AnimatedSprite background2;
    private AnimatedSprite Zero;
    private KeyboardState oldState;
    //starting place for Zero
    Vector2 lol = new Vector2(100, 200);

    Vector2 ground2 = new Vector2(0, 0);
    Vector2 ground = new Vector2(0, 0);
    Boolean jumping = false;

    Texture2D firstback;
    Texture2D texture2;
    Texture2D secondback;


   public Rectangle FirstBounds;
   public Rectangle SecondBounds;


    //Variables
    int timer = 0; //checks if it should update, helps to delay the update process.
    int jumptimer = 0;//uses as a timer for the amount of time you get to jump.
    int jumpanimation = 0;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 900;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1000;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        firstback = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tester");
        animatedSprite = new AnimatedSprite(firstback, 1, 1);

        secondback = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tester2");
        background2 = new AnimatedSprite(secondback, 1, 1);

        //Creates the sprite for Zero, the main character.
        texture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ZeroIdle");
        Zero = new AnimatedSprite(texture2, 1, 8);

        ground2 = new Vector2(ground.X + firstback.Width, 0);



    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }



    //Collision, took forever to figure out.
    public Boolean collision(Texture2D first, Vector2 position1, Texture2D second, Vector2 position2)
    {

        //gets the bounds of the two sprites
        FirstBounds = new Rectangle((int)(position1.X),
        (int)(position1.Y), first.Width, first.Height);

        SecondBounds = new Rectangle((int)(position2.X),
        (int)(position2.Y), second.Width, second.Height);

        //if they intersect.
            if (FirstBounds.Intersects(SecondBounds))
            {

            Color[] DataA = new Color[first.Width * first.Height];
            first.GetData(DataA);

            Color[] DataB = new Color[second.Width * second.Height];
            second.GetData(DataB);

            int Top = System.Math.Max(FirstBounds.Top, SecondBounds.Top);
            int Bottom = System.Math.Min(FirstBounds.Bottom, SecondBounds.Bottom);
            int Left = System.Math.Max(FirstBounds.Left, SecondBounds.Left);
            int Right = System.Math.Min(FirstBounds.Right, SecondBounds.Right);

            for (int y = Top; y < Bottom; y++)
            {
                for (int x = Left; x < Right; x++)
                {
                    Color ColorA = DataA[(x - FirstBounds.Left) + (y - FirstBounds.Top) * FirstBounds.Width];
                    Color ColorB = DataB[(x - SecondBounds.Left) + (y - SecondBounds.Top) * SecondBounds.Width];

                    if (ColorA.A > 0 && ColorB.A > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                }

            }

            return false;
            }





        return false;

    }



    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {


        KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState();



        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        //checks indivdual keystates, starts with if keys are down.






        if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && state.IsKeyUp(Keys.Left))
        {



            if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {



                //Makes it impossible to double jump. You need to wait until you finished your jump to jump again.

                if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up) && jumping == false && (collision(firstback, ground, texture2, lol) == true || collision(secondback, ground2, texture2, lol) == true))
                {
                    texture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ZeroJump");
                    Zero = new AnimatedSprite(texture2, 1, 14);
                    jumping = true;

                }
        }



            //checks to see if you've released the right key. Makes the game update properly.
            if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Right) && jumping == false && (collision(firstback, ground, texture2, lol) == true || collision(secondback, ground2, texture2, lol) == true))
            {
                texture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ZeroRunning");
                Zero = new AnimatedSprite(texture2, 1, 11);

            }



            oldState = state;



            //Causes a delay to make sure Zero updates properly and not at 60 times per second.
            if (timer >=3)
            {





                //moves Zero.
                Vector2 adding = new Vector2(5, 0);
                lol = Vector2.Add(lol, adding);
                Zero.Update();




                timer = 0;
            }

            else
                timer++;

            Vector2 aSpeed = new Vector2(-5, 0);
            ground = Vector2.Add(ground, aSpeed);
            ground2 = Vector2.Add(ground2, aSpeed);
        }




        else if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && state.IsKeyUp(Keys.Right))
        {



            if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {



                //Makes it impossible to double jump. You need to wait until you finished your jump to jump again.

                if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up) && jumping == false && (collision(firstback, ground, texture2, lol) == true || collision(secondback, ground2, texture2, lol) == true))
                {
                    texture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ZeroJump");
                    Zero = new AnimatedSprite(texture2, 1, 14);
                    jumping = true;

                }

            }




            //checks to see if you've released the right key. Makes the game update properly.

            if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Left) && jumping == false && (collision(firstback, ground, texture2, lol) == true || collision(secondback, ground2, texture2, lol) == true))
            {
                texture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ZeroRunningLeft");
                Zero = new AnimatedSprite(texture2, 1, 11);

            }

            oldState = state;


            //causes a delay in updating so Zero animates properly.
            if (timer >= 3)
            {
                //actually moves Zero.
                Vector2 adding = new Vector2(-5, 0);
                lol = Vector2.Add(lol, adding);
                Zero.Update();




                timer = 0;
            }



            else
                timer++;

                Vector2 aSpeed = new Vector2(5, 0);
                ground = Vector2.Add(ground, aSpeed);
                ground2 = Vector2.Add(ground2, aSpeed);
        }


        //Jumping State.
        if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {



            //Makes it impossible to double jump. You need to wait until you finished your jump to jump again.

            if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Up) && jumping == false && (collision(firstback, ground, texture2, lol) == true || collision(secondback, ground2, texture2, lol) == true))
            {
                texture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ZeroJump");
                Zero = new AnimatedSprite(texture2, 1, 14); 
                jumping = true;

            }



            oldState = state;




        }




        //Section that checks if the keys are up.

        if (state.IsKeyUp(Keys.Left) && state.IsKeyUp(Keys.Right) && jumping == false && (collision(firstback, ground, texture2, lol) == true || collision(secondback, ground2, texture2, lol) == true))
        {
            texture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ZeroIdle");
            Zero = new AnimatedSprite(texture2, 1, 8);
            timer = 0;
            oldState = (new KeyboardState());
        }





        //Gravity effects and updates.

        if (jumping == true)
        {                
                Vector2 adding = new Vector2(0, -5);
                lol = Vector2.Add(lol, adding);

                //times the animation.
                if (jumpanimation >= 5)
                {

                    Zero.Update();
                    jumpanimation = 0;

                }

                else
                    jumpanimation++;

                jumptimer++;

                if (jumptimer >= 30)
                {
                    jumping = false;
                    jumptimer = 0;

                    //whenever the timer has expired.
                    if (collision(firstback, ground, texture2, lol) == false)
                    {
                        texture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ZeroFalling");
                        Zero = new AnimatedSprite(texture2, 1, 4);
                    }


                    oldState = (new KeyboardState());

                }


        }

        else
        {
            if (collision(firstback, ground, texture2, lol) == false && collision(secondback, ground2, texture2, lol) == false)
            {
                Vector2 adding = new Vector2(0, 5);
                lol = Vector2.Add(lol, adding);
            }

            else if ((collision(firstback, ground, texture2, lol) == true || collision(secondback, ground2, texture2, lol) == true) == true && texture2 == Content.Load<Texture2D>("ZeroFalling"))
                oldState = (new KeyboardState());



        }


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);


        background2.Draw(spriteBatch, ground2);
        Zero.Draw(spriteBatch, lol);
        animatedSprite.Draw(spriteBatch, ground);

        base.Draw(gameTime);



    }

}
```

}

I'm not entirely sure what is wrong, any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have there looks correct, so the problem might be somewhere else, for example, the position is being updated too late or too soon. Any more code to post?

I would recommend the following tutorial:

http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started

It will help set up animation classes properly, so the proper frames are being used for detection.

Comment: I can post the entire class itself if you think it would help.

Comment: Well, first of all there is a lot strange code in here :p. Constantly loading the textures as you have will produce memory issues, they should be loaded into a variable once in LoadContent(). Also, are the textures truly animating (as in going frame by frame within the texture)? If so, the collision may be occurring if you are not checking the correct frame of the texture.

Comment: I found out that yes, you are right. I have updated it to make part of the collision work. The only problem is that I am having some issues with moving zero left and right.

Comment: Also I know =/ unfortunately that's the first animated sprite class I made and I am still using it,  it will be updated later to pull only certain rows and columns instead of the entire thing